# Treeview menu render twice categories in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, treeview, laravel-5

I have created nested treeview categories and subcategories but seems that it is rendering the categories twice.

This is what is happen and I see on page.

```
Main category 1
  - Sub -category 1.1
  - Sub -category 1.2
Main category 2
  - Sub -category 2.1
  - Sub -category 2.2
Sub -category 1.1
Sub -category 1.2
Sub -category 2.1
Sub -category 2.2
```

What is happening here is that first is render the correct treeview but then under is render sub-categories as main categories.

The categories and sub-categories are saved in one table where I have column `parent_id` 0 for main category and if is sub-category is the id of main-category instead. This is my model

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_id');
}
```

Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $allCategories = Category::with(['children'])->get();     
    return view('categories', compact('allCategories'));
}
```

and the blade

```
@foreach($allCategories as $category)
  <li class="treeview">
    <a href="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->title }}</a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
      @foreach($category->children as $subcategory)
        <li class=""><a href="{{$subcategory->id}}">{{$subcategory->title}}</a></li>
      @endforeach
    </ul>
  </li>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.

Model

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'id', 'parent_id'); // I believe you can use also hasOne().
}

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_id', 'id');
}
public static function tree() {

    return static::where('parent_id', '=', NULL)->get(); // or based on you question 0?

}
```

Your controller

```
public function index()
{
    $allCategories = Category::tree();     
    return view('categories', compact('allCategories'));
}
```

And your blade view

```
@foreach($allCategories as $item)
<li class="treeview">
    <a href="{{ $item->id }}"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>{{ $item->title }}</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
        <ul class="treeview-menu">
            @foreach($item['children'] as $child)
            <li><a href="{{ $child->id }}">{{ $child->title }}</a></li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
</li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: This is a problem because Eloquent make a query for each children. 
In my case, I have too many menus and submenus, Eloquent make 67 queries.

Install [Laravel DebugBar](https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) to see queries